# How to use <Link> and <Button> in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently using `React`.
My code uses `useForm` in the react to perform validation.

I want to go to `another page` when a user enters a nickname and presses the `Enter` key or clicks the `Button`.

Now my code is to put the `<button> tag` inside the `<Link> tag`, and it will not complete the validation and will immediately go to another page.

In the opposite case, my code does not go to another page. Help me :(

```js
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onValid)}>
          <input
            {...register("nickName", {
              required: true,
              minLength: {
                value: 2,
                message: "error",
              },
            })}
            className="join-input"
            placeholder="nickname here"
          />
          <div className="error-message">{errors?.nickName?.message}</div>

          <Link to={"/office"}>
            <button className="go-btn bttn-material-flat">Enter</button>
          </Link> 
        </form>
```

Comment: Buttons have no business in side anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the linking to the new page in your `handleSubmit` function e.g `handleSubmit(onSubmit)` and then:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
   // programatically link here, implementation differs depending on what framework you are using. 
};


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
   ...
</form>
```